# How can I stack two layers with completely different extents and resolutions?

Tags: raster, r

The title is pretty self explanatory. I have two rasters which are completely different

```
> TRI
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 15249, 17246, 262984254  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent     : 5194725, 5625875, 1517575, 1898800  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : TRI.tif 
names      : TRI 
values     : 0, 443.4239  (min, max)


class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 4320, 8640, 37324800, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values :   -40.5,   -47.7,     0.0 
max values :    43.4,    28.8,   980.0
```

Any clue as to how can I stack them?

Comment: Reproject one into the dimension and CRS of the other one?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the result? Why do you need it in a single stack? Could you instead do separate operations on the two source rasters? If not, what are you willing to compromise to warp one raster to another?

Comment: @Spacedman I would like to use them for species distributions and specifically maxent. I would like to retain some of the quality